# How to run a docker container with the exports of a `.bashrc`

Tags: bash, docker

I have a docker image inside which some installations require adding exports to `.bashrc`.
My export variables are inside `/root/.bashrc` on the image.

Here is the dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3

RUN echo "export PATH=/path/to/stuff:\$PATH" >> /root/.bashrc

CMD ["python3"]
```

The environment variables are present when using the following command

```
docker run -it image /bin/bash
```

When I run the following command, environment variables are not present.

```
docker run -it image
```

It is expected since `/bin/sh` is the default entry point of docker

But after the following change, the environment variable are not set either.

```
docker commit --change='ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","-c"]' container image
```

I tried different combinations such as

```
docker commit --change='CMD ["/bin/bash","-c","python3 myProgram.py"]' container image
```

or

```
docker commit --change='ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","-c"]' --change='CMD ["source /root/.bashrc && python3 myProgram.py"]' container image
```

But the environment variables are not present.

How do I run the CMD statement with the environment variable from `.bashrc` loaded ?

In order to see the path variable, I use `echo $PATH` when I run `/bin/bash` and `import os` followed by `os.getenv("PATH")` when I run `python3` from CMD.

Edit:

The exports are part of the installation of a library. In order to use the library, the updated exports (such as `PYTHONPATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) needs to be set.

If `.bashrc` is not intended to be launched, as mentioned in the comments. How can I make this library work in the docker environment ?

Comment: keyword `ENV` in DockerFile use for adding variables to your container .                                Kindly update your question with your DockerFile too

Comment: One of the env variable not updated is PATH, which is already present but does not contain what is added in the .bashrc.

Comment: use keyword `RUN` and the your script `echo "export PATH=/path/to/stuff:\$PATH" >> /root/.bashrc` in your DockerFile to add variable to your image while building it

Comment: `.bashrc` is only for _interactive_ shells. Noninteractive shells aren't expected to run it, and you shouldn't be writing scripts that assume things it defines will be available.

Comment: @itshosyn, for the reasons given above, that won't make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned [by @itshosyn in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68288235/how-to-run-a-docker-container-with-the-exports-of-a-bashrc#comment120689555_68288235), the standard way to override environment variables such as `PATH` consists in using the `ENV` directive.

So you may try writing something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3

ENV PATH="/path/to/stuff:$PATH"

CMD ["python3"]
```